# Erro com foreign key de outro banco

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando colocar foreign key relacionadas com tabelas de outro banco de dados (Estou realizando testes e as vezes preciso excluir o banco principal).

Entretanto esta apresentando os seguintes erros:

> Mensagem 1763, Nível 16, Estado 0, Linha 93 Não há suporte para
>   referências de chave estrangeira em todos os bancos de dados. Chave
>   estrangeira 'municipios.dbo.Estado'. Mensagem 1750, Nível 16, Estado
>   1, Linha 93 Não foi possível criar a restrição ou o índice. Consulte
>   os erros anteriores.

Tabela de Estado:

```
CREATE TABLE Estado (
    CodigoUf INT          NOT NULL,
    Nome     VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    Uf       CHAR    (2)  NOT NULL,
    Regiao   INT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CodigoUf),

constraint fk_Uf_Regiao foreign key (Regiao) references Regiao(Id)
);
```

Tabela que estou fazendo a foreign:

```
create table Clientes(
ID_int          int identity,
ID              AS RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ID_int AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) PERSISTED,
Loja            varchar(4),
Tipo            varchar(4),
CNPJ_CPF        varchar(14),
IE              varchar(14),
Nome            varchar(60),
nome_fantasia   varchar(60),
E_mail          varchar(60),
Telefone        varchar(20),
Endereco        varchar(30),
Bairro          varchar(30),
Cod_Mun         varchar(7),
Municipio       varchar(30),
Uf              int,
CEP             varchar(8),
Bloqueado       varchar(3) default 'NAO',
Forma_pagamento int,
data_cadastro   datetime,
ult_compra      datetime,
primeira_compra datetime,
Media_Atrasos   int,
Tabela_preco    varchar(3),
Tp_entrega      varchar(1),
grp_vendas      varchar(6),

constraint pk_Clientes primary key (CNPJ_CPF),
constraint fk_Clientes_UF foreign key (uf) references [municipios].[dbo].[Estado](CodigoUf) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
constraint fk_Clientes_Mun foreign key (Cod_Mun) references [municipios].[dbo].[Municipio](Cod_Mun) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
constraint fk_Clientes_Tabela foreign key (tabela_preco) references tabela_precos(id),
constraint fk_Clientes_grp foreign key (grp_vendas) references grupo_vendas(id)
)
go
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marcos, o texto em português da mensagem de erro 1763 não deixa claro qual é a causa:
"Não há suporte para referências de chave estrangeira em todos os bancos de dados"

Em "todos os bancos de dados"?!

--
Mas eis o texto original da mensagem de erro 1763:
"Cross-database foreign key references are not supported. Foreign key ‘%.*ls’"

Agora ficou claro qual o motivo do erro, certo? Em suma, *não é possível referências de chave estrangeira entre bancos de dados*.